# SyntaxError: unexpected end of XML source

Tags: php, xml, salesforce

I have a site and iam using saleforce.com .

This is my code:

```
function salesforce() {
    var first_name = $("#first_name_new").val();
    var last_name = $("#last_name_new").val();
    var coupon_code = $("#coupon_code_new").val();
    var phone = $("#phone_new").val();
    var email = $("#email_new").val();
    var state = $("#state_new").val();
    var oid = "00DU0000000HB32";
    var retURL = "http://www.testsite.com";
    var debug = "1";
    var debugEmail = "arnold@gmail.com"; 
    //alert(first_name_new+"/"+last_name+"/"+coupon_code+"/"+phone+"/"+email+"/"+state);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        url: "https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8",
        data: { first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name, phone: phone, email:email, state:state, oid:oid, debug:debug, debugEmail:debugEmail },
        success:function(data){
            contactSent = "true";

        },
        error:function(data){
            contactSent = "true";
        }   
    });
}
```

I called this function onclick of a button:

```
$(function(){
$('.next-product').click(function(){
                 salesforce();
 });
});
```

This is the button:

```
 <button class="next-product">Next</button>
```

When i clicked on the button it displays error in bug as:

```
SyntaxError: unexpected end of XML source
<BR><BR>Your request has been queued.<BR><BR>Record Information:<BR><BR>_: 1345203119160<BR>callback: jQuery172007126272654237087_1345203087782<BR>debug: 1<BR>debugEmail: arnold@gmail.com<BR>email: mariya@galtech.org<BR>encoding: UTF-8<BR>first_name: ttt<BR>last_name: tttteee<BR>oid: 00DU0000000HB32<BR>phone: 1234567896<BR>state: kerala<BR>
```

How can i solve this?

EDIT:

This is the whole code in the page iam using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>TradeYourWreck.com | Wrecked Car? Don&#039;t sell it&#8230; Fix it</title>
        <link href="tyw.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link type="text/css" href="css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajaxupload.3.5.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.carqueryapi.com/js/carquery.0.3.3.js"></script>
        <!--[if lte IE 7]>
<style>
.content { margin-right: -1px; } /* this 1px negative margin can be placed on any of the columns in this layout with the same corrective effect. */
ul.nav a { zoom: 1; }  /* the zoom property gives IE the hasLayout trigger it needs to correct extra whiltespace between the links */
</style>
<![endif]-->
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
function()
{
     //Create a variable for the CarQuery object.  You can call it whatever you like.
     var carquery = new CarQuery();

     //Run the carquery init function to get things started:
     carquery.init();

     //Optionally, you can pre-select a vehicle by passing year / make / model / trim to the init function:
     //carquery.init('2000', 'dodge', 'Viper', 11636);

     //Optional: Pass sold_in_us:true to the setFilters method to show only US models. 
     carquery.setFilters( {sold_in_us:true} );

     //Optional: initialize the year, make, model, and trim drop downs by providing their element IDs
     carquery.initYearMakeModelTrim('car-years', 'car-makes', 'car-models', 'car-model-trims');

     //Optional: set the onclick event for a button to show car data.
     $('#cq-show-data').click(  function(){ carquery.populateCarData('car-model-data'); } );

     //Optional: initialize the make, model, trim lists by providing their element IDs.
     carquery.initMakeModelTrimList('make-list', 'model-list', 'trim-list', 'trim-data-list');

     //Optional: set minimum and/or maximum year options.
     carquery.year_select_min=1980;
     carquery.year_select_max=2012;

     //Optional: initialize search interface elements.
     //The IDs provided below are the IDs of the text and select inputs that will be used to set the search criteria.
     //All values are optional, and will be set to the default values provided below if not specified.
     var searchArgs =
     ({
         body_id:                       "cq-body"
        ,default_search_text:           "Keyword Search"
        ,doors_id:                      "cq-doors"
        ,drive_id:                      "cq-drive"
        ,engine_position_id:            "cq-engine-position"
        ,engine_type_id:                "cq-engine-type"
        ,fuel_type_id:                  "cq-fuel-type"
        ,min_cylinders_id:              "cq-min-cylinders"
        ,min_mpg_hwy_id:                "cq-min-mpg-hwy"
        ,min_power_id:                  "cq-min-power"
        ,min_top_speed_id:              "cq-min-top-speed"
        ,min_torque_id:                 "cq-min-torque"
        ,min_weight_id:                 "cq-min-weight"
        ,min_year_id:                   "cq-min-year"
        ,max_cylinders_id:              "cq-max-cylinders"
        ,max_mpg_hwy_id:                "cq-max-mpg-hwy"
        ,max_power_id:                  "cq-max-power"
        ,max_top_speed_id:              "cq-max-top-speed"
        ,max_weight_id:                 "cq-max-weight"
        ,max_year_id:                   "cq-max-year"
        ,search_controls_id:            "cq-search-controls"
        ,search_input_id:               "cq-search-input"
        ,search_results_id:             "cq-search-results"
        ,search_result_id:              "cq-search-result"
        ,seats_id:                      "cq-seats"
        ,sold_in_us_id:                 "cq-sold-in-us"
     }); 
     carquery.initSearchInterface(searchArgs);

     //If creating a search interface, set onclick event for the search button.  Make sure the ID used matches your search button ID.
     $('#cq-search-btn').click( function(){ carquery.search(); } );
});
</script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var contactSent = "false";

    $(function(){
        //$("#tabVPhoto").hide();
        $("#tabPkg").hide();
        $('#tabs').tabs({
            fx: { 
                opacity: 'toggle' 
            }
        });
    });

    function lookupVIN() {
        //console.log("lookup vin");
        var car_vin = $("#car-vin").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "vin.php",
            data: { car_vin: car_vin },
            success:function(data){
                //console.log(data);
                $("#vinDet").html(data);
                //vinDet
            },
            error:function(data){
            }   
        });

    }

    function salesforce() {
        var first_name = $("#first_name").val();
        var last_name = $("#last_name").val();
        var phone = $("#phone").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var state = $("#state").val();
        var oid = "00DU0000000HB32";
        var retURL = "http://www.tradeyourwreck.com";
        var debug = "1";
        var debugEmail = "arnold@vemark.com"; 

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            url: "https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8",
            data: { first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name, phone: phone, email:email, state:state, oid:oid, debug:debug, debugEmail:debugEmail },
            success:function(data){
                contactSent = "true";
            },
            error:function(data){
                contactSent = "true";
            }   
        });
    }

    $(function(){
        $('.next-product').click(function(){
            var index = jQuery('#tabs').data('tabs').options.selected;
            //console.log(contactSent);
            var pkg = $('input:radio[name=pkg]:checked').val();
            /*
            if(pkg=="self") {
                $("#tabVPhoto").show();
                $("#tabVCond").show();
                $("#self").show();
                $("#inspect").hide();
            }else {
                $("#tabVPhoto").hide();
                $("#tabVCond").hide();
                $("#self").hide();
                $("#inspect").show();
                //alert('inspect');
            }
            */
            var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs();
            var selected = $tabs.tabs('option', 'selected');
            $tabs.tabs('select', selected+1);

            if(index==0) {
             if(contactSent == "false"){
                 salesforce();
             }
            }

    })
    $('.previous-product').click(function(){ 
            var index = jQuery('#tabs').data('tabs').options.selected;
            //console.log(index);
                    var pkg = $('input:radio[name=pkg]:checked').val();
                    if(pkg=="self") {
                        $("#tabVPhoto").show();
                        $("#tabVCond").show();

                    }else {
                        $("#tabVPhoto").hide();
                        $("#tabVCond").hide();
                        //alert('inspect');
                    }



                    var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs();
                    var selected = $tabs.tabs('option', 'selected');
                    $tabs.tabs('select', selected-1);
                })

                $( '.next-product').button({
                    text: true,
                    icons: {
                    primary: "ui-icon-seek-next"
                    }
                });

                $( '.previous-product' ).button({
                    text: true,
                    icons: {
                        primary: "ui-icon-seek-prev"
                    }
                });

            }); 

    $(function(){
        var cntUp = 0;


        var btnUpload=$('#upload');
        var status=$('#status');
        new AjaxUpload(btnUpload, {
            action: 'upload-file.php',
            name: 'uploadfile',
            onSubmit: function(file, ext){
                 if (! (ext && /^(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$/.test(ext))){ 
                    // extension is not allowed 
                    alert('Only JPG, PNG or GIF files are allowed');
                    return false;
                }
                status.text('Uploading...');
            },
            onComplete: function(file, response){
                //On completion clear the status
                status.text('image uploaded');
                cntUp++;
                //console.log(cntUp);
                //Add uploaded file to list
                if (response.toLowerCase().indexOf("success") >= 0 ) {
                //alert('success');
                $('<li></li>').appendTo('#files').html('<img src="uploads/'+file+'" alt="" /><br />'+file).addClass('success');
                }  else{
                    $('<li></li>').appendTo('#files').text(file).addClass('error');
                    //alert('error');
                }
            }
        });

    });


        </script>
        </head>

        <body>
<div class="container">
          <div class="header">
    <nav id="access" role="navigation">
              <div class="menu-top-menu-container">
        <ul id="menu-top-menu" class="menu">
                  <li id="menu-item-30" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-25 current_page_item menu-item-30"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                  <li id="menu-item-21" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-21"><a href="about.php">About TradeYourWreck.com</a></li>
                  <li id="menu-item-22" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-22"><a href="inquiries.php">Inquiries</a></li>
                </ul>
      </div>
            </nav>
    <a href="index.php"> <img src="images/header1.jpg" width="1000" height="163" alt=""> </a> </div>
          <?php include 'inc/sidebar.php'; ?>
          <div class="content">
    <div style="width:675px; margin: 0 auto; margin-top:10px; font-size:12px;" id="tabs">
              <ul>
        <!--<li id="tabPkg"><a href="#tabs-1">Select Your Package</a></li> -->
        <li id="tabVInfo"><a href="#tabs-2">Contact Information</a></li>
        <li id="tabVCond"><a href="#tabs-3">Vehicle Information</a></li>
        <li id="tabVPhoto"><a href="#tabs-4">Additional Vehicle Information</a></li>
        <li id="tabVCheck"><a href="#tabs-5">Check Out</a></li>
      </ul>
              <div id="tabs-2">
        <input type=hidden name="oid" value="00DU0000000HB32">
        <input type=hidden name="retURL" value="http://www.tradeyourwreck.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="debug" value=1>
        <input type="hidden" name="debugEmail" value="arnold@vemark.com">
        <!--<input type="hidden" name="debugEmail" value="jweeks@thoughtwm.com">-->
        <table cellpadding="3">
                  <tr>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td><input  id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" /></td>
          </tr>
                  <tr>
            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td><input  id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" /></td>
          </tr>
                  <tr>
            <td>Phone</td>
            <td><input  id="phone" maxlength="40" name="phone" size="20" type="text" /></td>
          </tr>
                  <tr>
            <td>Email Address</td>
            <td><input  id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="30" type="text" /></td>
          </tr>
                  <tr>
            <td>State/Province</td>
            <td><input  id="state" maxlength="20" name="state" size="20" type="text" /></td>
          </tr>
                  <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><button class="previous-product">Previous</button>
                      <button class="next-product">Next</button></td>
          </tr>
                </table>
        ​ </div>
              <div id="tabs-3"> 

        <!--   -->

        <table cellpadding="3">
                  <tr>
            <td valign="top">VIN</td>
            <td>
<!-- test VINS:
 1GDGG31Z4RF513458<br/>
                      KMHCG45C31U211444<br/>
                      2MEFM75W7YX721741<br/>
-->
                      <input class="frmIn" size="30" value="" name="car-vin" id="car-vin" type="text" value="" />
                      <input onclick="lookupVIN()" name="btnVin" type="button" value="Lookup" />
                      <br/>
                      <div id="vinDet"></div></td>
          </tr>
                  <tr>
            <td>Year</td>
            <td><select name="car-years" id="car-years">
              </select></td>
          </tr>
                  <tr>
            <td>Make</td>
            <td><select name="car-makes" id="car-makes">
              </select></td>
          </tr>
                  <tr>
            <td>Model</td>
            <td><select name="car-models" id="car-models">
              </select></td>
          </tr>
                  <!--<tr>
                     <td>Trims</td>
                     <td><select name="car-model-trims" id="car-model-trims"></select></td>
                     </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Color</td>
                <td><input class="frmIn" name="car-color" type="text" value="" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Mileage</td>
                <td><input class="frmIn" name="car-mileage" type="text" value="" /></td>
              </tr> 
              <tr>
                <td>Repair Estimate</td>
                <td><input class="frmIn" name="car-estimate" type="text" value="" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Reserve Price</td>
                <td><input class="frmIn" name="car-reserve" type="text" value="" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Secondary Damage</td>
                <td><input class="frmIn" name="car-damage" type="text" value="" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Comments</td>
                <td><textarea class="frmIn" name="car-comment" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea></td>
              </tr>-->
                  <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><button class="previous-product">Previous</button>
                      <button class="next-product">Next</button></td>
          </tr>
                </table>
        ​ </div>
              <div id="tabs-4">
        <table cellpadding="3">
                  <tr>
            <td>Repair Estimate</td>
            <td><input class="frmIn" name="car-estimate" type="text" value="" /></td>
          </tr>
                  <tr>
            <td>Reserve Price</td>
            <td><input class="frmIn" name="car-reserve" type="text" value="" /></td>
          </tr>
                  <tr>
            <td>Primary Damage</td>
            <td><select name="car-damage">
                <option value="Center Rear">Center Rear</option>
                <option value="Chemical Spill">Chemical Spill</option>
                <option value="Dash Fire">Dash Fire</option>
                <option value="Engine">Engine</option>
                <option value="Engine Fire">Engine Fire</option>
                <option value="Fallen Tree">Fallen Tree</option>
                <option value="Fresh Water">Fresh Water</option>
                <option value="Hail Damage">Hail Damage</option>
                <option value="Hard Roll">Hard Roll</option>
                <option value="Interior Fire">Interior Fire</option>
                <option value="Left Front">Left Front</option>
                <option value="Left Rear">Left Rear</option>
                <option value="Left Side">Left Side</option>
                <option value="Lite Fire Damage">Lite Fire Damage</option>
                <option value="Lite Roll">Lite Roll</option>
                <option value="Medium Roll">Medium Roll</option>
                <option value="None">None</option>
                <option value="Right Front">Right Front</option>
                <option value="Right Rear">Right Rear</option>
                <option value="Right Side">Right Side</option>
                <option value="Rolled">Rolled</option>
                <option value="Roof">Roof</option>
                <option value="Salt Water">Salt Water</option>
                <option value="Theft Heavy Strip">Theft Heavy Strip</option>
                <option value="Theft Lite Strip">Theft Lite Strip</option>
                <option value="Theft Recovery">Theft Recovery</option>
                <option value="Total Burn">Total Burn</option>
                <option value="Undercarriage">Undercarriage</option>
                <option value="Vandalized">Vandalized</option>
                <option value="Transmission">Transmission</option>
                <option value="Center Front">Center Front</option>
                <option value="Mechanical">Mechanical</option>
              </select></td>
          </tr>
                </table>
        <div style="margin-top:15px;" id="mainbody" >
                  <div id="upload" style="margin-bottom:10px;" ><span>Upload Photos<span></div>
                  <!--<span id="status" >status</span> -->

                  <ul id="files" >
          </ul>
                  <button class="previous-product">Previous</button>
                  <button class="next-product">Next</button>
                </div>
        ​ </div>
              <div id="tabs-5">
        <div id="self"> 
                  <!--              <table border="0">
                <tr>
                  <td><form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
                      <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
                      <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="U3XMXN3S94BB6">
                      <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
                      <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
                    </form></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><img src="images/packages_img1.png" width="286" height="95" alt="Let us Do The work" /></td>
                </tr>

              </table> --> 
                </div>
        <div id="inspect">

                  <table border="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                      <td><form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
                          <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
                          <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="U3XMXN3S94BB6">
                          <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
                          <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
                        </form></td>
                      <td><img src="images/packages_img1.png" width="286" height="95" alt="Let us Do The work" /></td>
                    </tr>
            <tr>
                      <td><form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
                          <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
                          <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="XEEB6CNLRWJAJ">
                          <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
                          <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
                        </form></td>
                      <td><img src="images/packages_img2.png" width="286" height="95" alt="Let us Do The work" /></td>
                    </tr>
          </table>

                  <!--              <table border="0">

                <tr>
                  <td align="center"><form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
                      <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
                      <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="XEEB6CNLRWJAJ">
                      <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
                      <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
                    </form></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><img src="images/packages_img2.png" width="286" height="95" alt="Let us Do The work" /></td>
                </tr>

              </table>
 --> </div>
      </div>
            </div>
  </div>
     <p>&nbsp;</p>   </div>
<?php include 'inc/footer.php'; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a response from your server. We would need to see the code of the web service (PHP) being called to see what's going on there. It's not an error in what you have done.

Comment: This is the only code available for me...

Comment: Then you really need to speak to whomever runs the back-end service, since with the information provided you cannot solve this problem.

Comment: that would probably be a missing tag. check your syntax

Comment: @ Bhuvan ,where i check that tag...?

Comment: in your `<script>`. You can't do anything if this is the only snippet which you have! You should ask for the complete code

Comment: @ Bhuvan, the code in the page iam used is in the question...